# Numpy loadtxt: ValueError: Wrong number of columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Having the file TEST.txt structured as following:

```
a   45
b   45  55
c   66
```

When I try to open it:

```
import numpy as np
a= np.loadtxt(r'TEST.txt',delimiter='\t',dtype=str)
```

I have got the following error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2

It's clearly due to the fact that the second line has three columns instead of two, but I can't find an answer to my problem using the documentation.

Is there anyway I can fix it keeping all the data into an array?

In Matlab I can do something like:

```
a=textscan(fopen('TEST.txt'),'%s%s%s');
```

Something similar in Python would be apreciated.

Comment: what should happen to the extra one?

Comment: how do you want store them? can you write down the expected output?

Comment: what would the shape of the array be if you were to keep all?

Comment: @GM,  I think what you want is just not possible using loadtxt, you could do it using python with lists

Comment: You could do `arr = [line.split() for line in f]` where f is a file object

Comment: Or functionally  `arr = list(map(str.split, f))` which will give you `['a', '45'], ['b', '45', '55'], ['c', '66']]`

Comment: `with open('TEST.txt') as f:arr = list(map(str.split, f))`

Comment: Obviously you won't be able to do with a list what you can with a numpy array but it is the only way I can think of doing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `np.genfromtxt`.  It handles missing values; `loadtxt` does not.  Compare their docs.

Missing values can be tricky when the delimiter is white space, but with tabs it should be ok.  If there still are problems, test it with a `,` delimiter.

oops - you still need the extra delimiter

eg.

```
a, 34, 
b, 43, 34
c, 34
```

Both `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` accept any iterable that delivers the txt line by line.  So a simple thing is to `readlines`, tweak the lines that have missing values and delimiters, and pass that list of lines to the loader.  Or you can write this a 'filter' or generator.  This approach has been described in a number of previous SO questions.

```
In [36]: txt=b"""a\t45\t\nb\t45\t55\nc\t66\t""".splitlines()
In [37]: txt
Out[37]: [b'a\t45\t', b'b\t45\t55', b'c\t66\t']
In [38]: np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter='\t',dtype=str)
Out[38]: 
array([['a', '45', ''],
       ['b', '45', '55'],
       ['c', '66', '']], 
      dtype='<U2')
```

I'm using Python3 so the byte strings are marked with a 'b' (for baby and me).

For strings, this is overkill; but `genfromtxt` makes it easy to construct a structured array with different dtypes for each column.  Note that such array is 1d, with named fields - not numbered columns.

```
In [50]: np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter='\t',dtype=None)
Out[50]: 
array([(b'a', 45, -1), (b'b', 45, 55), (b'c', 66, -1)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

to pad the lines I could define a function like:

```
def foo(astr,delimiter=b',',cnt=3,fill=b' '):
    c = astr.strip().split(delimiter)
    c.extend([fill]*cnt)
    return delimiter.join(c[:cnt])
```

and use it as:

```
In [85]: txt=b"""a\t45\nb\t45\t55\nc\t66""".splitlines()

In [87]: txt1=[foo(txt[0],b'\t',3,b'0') for t in txt]
In [88]: txt1
Out[88]: [b'a\t45\t0', b'a\t45\t0', b'a\t45\t0']
In [89]: np.genfromtxt(txt1,delimiter='\t',dtype=None)
Out[89]: 
array([(b'a', 45, 0), (b'a', 45, 0), (b'a', 45, 0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Comment: hmm, I just tried genfromtxt() on a data format 1,2,3;1,2;1,2,3,4 and it's giving me error Line #3 (got 4 columns instead of 6)

Comment: Yes, it does that if the number of columns isn't same.  Make sure you are using the right delimiter.

Comment: yup, adding delimiter helps, but it reshapes it. Is there a way to keep original format?

Comment: With a well formatted csv there is only one possible shape.  Well, two if you specify a compound dtype and structured array.  Without seeing part of your file I have no idea of what shape and dtype it should have.  Comments is not the place to debug this.

Answer (score 4):

if you have variable number of columns you can't define a proper `np.array` shape. 
If you want to store them in an `np.array` try:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.loadtxt(r'TEST.txt', delimiter='\n', dtype=str)
```

now `a` is `array(['a   45', 'b   45  55', 'c   66'])`.

But in this case is better a list:

```
with open(r'TEST.txt') as f:
    a = f.read().splitlines()
```

now `a` is a list `['a   45', 'b   45  55', 'c   66']`

Answer (score 4):

If you want all rows to have the same number of columns but some have missing values you can do it easily with pandas. But you have to know the total number of columns.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('foo.txt', sep='\t', names=['col_a','col_b'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a bit to use the above solutions, so for someone needing an alternative, here is one:

My test.dat file has:

```
0   1   2
3   4   5
6
7   8   9
10  11  12
13
```

Code to read above file, and flatten it out in an array:

```
import numpy as np

filename = 'test.dat'

i = 1
data=[]

with open(filename) as ff:
    for line in ff: #To read a file line by line
        p = []
        p = line.split( ) #To split the elements being read in above line
        if i%3 == 0: #This is to read only one element when column number is different
            data.append(p[0])
        else:
            data.append(p[0])
            data.append(p[1])
            data.append(p[2])
            
        i = i + 1

print(data)
```

The output is:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']
```