# Python generate from list instead of Genfromtext

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate a numpy array with named columns from list. I dont know how to do it so now i use temp txt file to use it with genfromtxt numpy function.

```
my_data = np.genfromtxt('tmp.txt',delimiter='|', dtype=None, names ["Num", "Date", "Desc", "Rgh" ,"Prc", "Color", "Smb", "MType"])
```

How to get rid of genfromtxt cause i need to generate the same structure array from list of strings instead of file

Comment: Are you looking for [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### List of strings

For a list of strings, you can use `genfromtxt` directly.  It accepts any iterable that can feed it strings/lines one at a time.  I use this approach all the time when answering `genfromtxt` questions, e.g. in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35874408/901925

```
In [186]: txt='1|abc|Red|no'
In [187]: txt=[txt,txt,txt]
In [188]: A=np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None, delimiter='|')

In [189]: A
Out[189]: 
array([(1, 'abc', 'Red', 'no'), (1, 'abc', 'Red', 'no'),
       (1, 'abc', 'Red', 'no')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', 'S3'), ('f2', 'S3'), ('f3', 'S2')])
```

In Python3 there's the added complication of byte strings v. regular ones.

### List of values

In ways `genfromtxt` is an easy of creating a structured array. But with a few key facts, it isn't hard to generate it directly.

First, define the `dtype`.  There are various ways of doing this.

```
dt = np.dtype([('name1',int),('name2',float),('name3','S10'),...])
```

I usually test this expression in an interactive shell.

```
A = np.zeros((n,), dtype=dt)
```

creates an 'blank' array of the correct type.  Try it with a small `n`, and print the result.

Now try assigning values.  The easiest is by field

```
A['name1'] = [1,2,3]
A['name3'] = ['abc','def',...]
```

Or by record

```
A[0] = (1, 1.23, 'str', ...)
```

multiple records are assign values with a list of tuples.  That is the key.  For a 2d array, a list of lists works; but for a structured 1d array the elements have to be tuples.

```
A = np.array([(1,1.2,'abc'),(2,342.,'xyz'),(3,0,'')], dtype=dt)
```

Sometimes it helps to use a list comprehension to turn a list of lists into a list of tuples.

```
alist = [[1,1.0,'str'],[]...]
A[:] = [tuple(l) for l in alist]
```

Comment: But is there a function to create the same array as genfromtxt but from list instead of file

Comment: What does your list look like?  List of values like I describe or list of strings (file lines)?

Comment: Yes it is a list of strings with separator |. Just like this: 1|abc|Red|no this is example of one string the other strings are the same structure

Comment: Sorry, I missed the 'list of strings' in the text; see my edit

Comment: Thank yo very much hpaulj

Comment: Some of my old code using the approach with the list of strings stopped working and gives "TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly". The toy example provided here does the same. Has the API changed?