# Numpy - genfromtxt - partly missing last colums

Tags: python, numpy

I got a problem to load data from a file with numpy.
All tries to add the missing data failed for some reason.
IN a nut shell a file used for a while has a new column.

My data looks like:

ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL,MNO

obviously the array should be with 5 columns.
The first missing rows with only 4 columns should be filled with e.g. "ZZZ"

Even when I defined 5 columsn, getfromtxt return:

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 2080, in genfromtxt
raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #10191 (got 5 columns instead of 4)

my code so far:

`a = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype='object,object,object,object,object', delimiter=',',unpack=True, filling_values=0)`

many thanks for your help
HEP

Comment: You may need to read this in to a list by hand and convert to an np array after you have it in memory.

Comment: What do you mean by 'define 5 columns'?

Comment: It does not add fill values if delimiters are missing

Comment: define 5 columns => dtype='object,object,object,object,object' (5x "object")

Comment: I think the `dtype` is applied after loading lines.  It does not tell it  how many columns to create, expect, or pad-to.  `genfromtxt` is complex; don't make assumptions that aren't supported by the docs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871920/numpy-loadtxt-valueerror-wrong-number-of-columns